# Почему метод выполняется после его завершения

Tags: java, android-studio, методы

Вопрос возник из-за того, что в методе chooseButton было несколько buttonListener, а при вызове одной из них, менялась boolean переменная и  цвет Одной кнопки, потом программа должна была выйти из метода и напечатать End. Но случилось так, что программа прошла полностью метод chooseButton напечатала End, а когда я решил нажать на кнопки, то они обе поменяли свой цвет, хотя должна менять цвет лишь одна, и сработал вывод сообщения, хотя по-идее метод уже выполнился.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваши `onClick` обработчики не выполняются внутри `chooseButtonOnStart`, а только прикрепляются к соответствующим кнопкам.

Comment: код в вопросе должен быть размещен текстом, а не скриншотом и офомлен соответствующим образом (отступ в четыре пробела)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что слушатель кликов `OnClickListener` вызывается системой и срабатывает по событию нажатия кнопки. После того, как вы привязали слушатель к виджету методом `setOnClickListener()` он будет срабатывать при каждом нажатии на виджет. Это никак не зависит от завершения вашего собственного метода и будет действовать, пока виджет, к которому привязан слушатель находится на экране (и вы можете на него нажать), либо слушатель не будет явно отключен от этого виджета.

Если вы хотите, чтобы при завершении вашего метода кнопки перестали реагировать на клики, нужно отвязать от них слушатели кликов:

```
buttonA.setOnClickListener(null);
```